# How to develop and compile with hardhat using imports with different pragma/compiler versions?

Tags: solidity, chainlink

hardhat does not support https imports. After installing openzeppelin and chainlink with npm and using @openzeppelin/@chainlink, we get pragma/compiler version issues, even with different compiler versions in hardhat.config.js, and even with overwrites. How do you develop and compile with hardhat and these imports?

Answer (score 6):

In your `hardhat.config.js` you can add multiple compilers.

```js
module.exports = {
    solidity: {
        compilers: [
            {
                version: "0.6.6"
            },
            {
                version: "0.4.24"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Patrick. As mentioned in the description we tried multiple compilers and with all combinations and even with overwrites. 

In general: how to deal with contracts with pragma 0.a.b that imports a contract with pragma 0.c.d that imports ...etc.

```These files import other files that use a different and incompatible version of Solidity:

  * contracts/x.sol (0.a.b) imports @chainlink/contracts/.../y.sol (0.c.d)```

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: MacOS.
npx hardhat --version
2.2.0

Comment: Ah, it might be a Mac thing actually. I’ve had issues downloading packages with Mac but fine on Linux

Comment: Hm, that's weird. But then again, if this fixes the import issue, what's the best approach to deal with multiple compilers? Do you just let your hardhat.config.js grow with every compiler version a new (imported) contract needs?

Comment: At the moment, that's the solution that I've used. Maybe we can shop this issue over to the hardhat community and get an answer there too.

Comment: Ok, I see. We will try that on a linux machine. Thanks Patrick.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem, i wanted to interface with Venus protocol....so i basically put all the interfaces and the contract inside one file with the contract to avoid running multiple instances of the solidity compiler.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).